# Reading files by pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a reader for files by their name. Write regex mask:

```py
def getmatches(datafilelist, regex=None):
    """Takes list of search strings + regex. Returns a list of match objects"""
    if not regex:
        regex = re.compile(
            r"""
            (?P<ftype>[A-Z0-9]{5})      # band type of data file
            _[a-z]+                     # sat id
            _d(?P<date>\d{8})           # acq date
            _t(?P<time>\d{7})           # granule start time UTC
            _e\d+                       # granule end time UTC
            _b(?P<orbit>\d+)            # orbit number
            _c\d+                       # file creation date/time
            _\w+.h5                     # more stuff
            """, re.X)
    return [regex.search(filename) for filename in datafilelist]
```

File Name: SVI01_j01_d20191004_t0717193_e0730075_b00001_c20191004083048126000_ipop_dev.h5

What's wrong?

Comment: "sat id" is expected to be an underscore followed by lowercase letters (`_[a-z]+`) but in your example the actual value is "_j01" which contains numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just missing a few small things:

```
(?P<ftype>[A-Z0-9]{5})_[a-z0-9]+_d(?P<date>\d{8})_t(?P<time>\d{7})_e\d+_b(?P<orbit>\d+)_c\d+_\w+\.h5
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r'(?P<ftype>[A-Z0-9]{5})_[a-z0-9]+_d(?P<date>\d{8})_t(?P<time>\d{7})_e\d+_b(?P<orbit>\d+)_c\d+_\w+\.h5'
string = '''
SVI01_j01_d20191004_t0717193_e0730075_b00001_c20191004083048126000_ipop_dev.h5
'''

print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

#### Output

```
[('SVI01', '20191004', '0717193', '00001')]
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lnZdUz/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/lnZdUz/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---